# Does BouncyCastle have a SecureRandom service?

Tags: java, android, bouncycastle

I'm trying to generate cryptographically secure random numbers using Java and using the following code section to create a SecureRandom object to view its provider and algorithm:

```
Provider prov=new org.spongycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider();
Security.insertProviderAt(prov, 1);

SecureRandom sr=new SecureRandom();
srProvider=sr.getProvider().toString();
srAlgorithm=sr.getAlgorithm();
```

(spongy castle is bouncy castle equivalent for android made by Roberto Tyley - https://github.com/rtyley)

When I display provider and algorithm, it shows: Crypto version 1.0 SHA1PRNG

What surprises me is that the provider isn't Spongycastle even if it is installed as the first provider in the code. I'd like to ask you a) Isn't SecureRandom implemented in Spongy Castle (or Bouncy Castle). b) What "Crypto version 1.0"  exactly is (I mean is it Sun JCE provider or what?)

Thanks...

Rubi

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you are running on Android (you didn't state this explicitly). Bouncy Castle does not provide a `SecureRandom` implementation. 'Crypto' is the Apache Harmony (on which most of Android's core Java code is based on) JCE provider. There is no Sun JCE code in Android. BTW, the 'Crypto' provider only provides SHA1PRNG (RNG), SHA-1 (hash) and SHA1withDSA (signature) implementations. Everything else is provided by either Bouncy Castle or the OpenSSL-based provider.

Question: Why do you think you need a `SecureRandom` implementation from Bouncy/Spongy Castle?

Comment: Thanks Nikolay. Just wanted to know if SHA1PRNG has an alternative or not. It'd be good to check SHA1PRNG and others in randomness check tools.

Comment: At least on ICS (stock Galaxy Nexus) that is the only `SecureRandom` implementation. SHA1PRNG is a PRNG so it's only as good as the seed you give it. And it's seeded from `/dev/urandom`, so it might not be that great. Again, this is for ICS, but I doubt it would be any different on other versions. `/dev/random` can be painfully slow on Android, so I guess that's why it's not used. Do link it here if you actually check with a tool.

Comment: @ Nikolay Elenkov: Thanks for the info. How can I see if dev/random or dev/urandom is used on my Android device as seed source and how can I change it dynamically in my code?

Comment: You need to check out the source code of your particular Android build. It's most probably `/dev/urandom`. I don't think you can change the way the system implementation behaves. You can copy the code in your project and reconfigure it as you please though.

Comment: Google probably added to the confusion with the blog post on security enhancements in 4.2, where they specifically mention "[t]he old Bouncy Castle-based implementation[...]". http://android-developers.blogspot.co.at/2013/02/security-enhancements-in-jelly-bean.html

Answer (score 8):

Bouncy Castle *does* provide a set of **Pseudo** Random Number Generators (PRNGs). There are many names for PRNG's; NIST calls them **Deterministic** Random Bit Generators (DRBGs). They are however only available in the "Lightweight" API of Bouncy Castle, in the package `org.bouncycastle.crypto.prng`.

However, Bouncy Castle is a software-only implementation of cryptographic algorithms. This means that it doesn't contain a source for *entropy*. Entropy cannot be generated by software alone as software algorithms themselves are deterministic. So even if the Bouncy Castle provider would register some of the generators in its `"BC"` provider (or Spongy provider for Android) then it would still have to rely on the same entropy source as the platform `SecureRandom` implementation.

As the entropy source is likely the culprit for most performance issues, you should not expect wonders of Bouncy Castle with regards to random number generation efficiency.

Currently (v1.54) the Bouncy Castle provider doesn't register any `SecureRandom` implementations at all, so there's that.

Comment: Looks like Bouncy Castle 1.57 is registering a `SecureRandom` implementation.